# Run PHP file in the background

Tags: php, mysql

I wonder if it is possible to run a PHP file in the background on my website?

What I want to do is to show a form with inputs and dropdowns. The content of the dropdown is taken from a table in a MySQL database. Next to the dropdown is an Edit button which opens a Bootstrap Modal and shows all the content in the table for the dropdown. Here I can make changes to the table. Then I want to go back to the form and apply the changes I jsut made (i.e. select a new post from the dropdown).

I know how to do all of this - BUT - when I save the changes to the dropdown table, a php file is called to perform the SQL syntax and then redirects the user back to the form. Every input you have made in the form is lost since the page is reloaded.

Is there a way to make it work like I want?

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at Websockets. I'm not sure but I think you can keep a connection open with it

Comment: I think what you are looking for are ajax queries http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp They will allow you to send data to the server to be saved, without reloading the form.

Comment: I have been looking at the W3 school but I just can't figure out how to do it. Can somebody please help me? :(

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you need to implement Ajax to do the background operation. Ajax request runs in background, its entry and exit is handled through Javascript functions . See here : http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: I have been looking at the W3 school but I just can't figure out how to do it. Can somebody please help me? :(

Answer (score 0):

As some already noted, [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX) is the way to go in this case.

An idea would be to use ajax to send the modal data to the server (saving the new options for the dropdown) when the user clicks in the "save" button (or anything equivalent). When this ajax call finish successfully, you could reload the dropdown with another ajax call (or even better, save the modal data in a temporary structure in JavaScript and use it to update the dropdown once the first ajax call is successful, hence avoiding some work on the server)

Note that the page won't reload in the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and the easiest way to do this is to open the modal in a new window.

example

```
<a href="Modal.html" target="_new">Modal</a>
```

And you can attached this to your select option value with a on-click event.